# Rails 5: Cache for DynamoDB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, redis, memcached

I run the same Ruby on Rails app on many instances. Currently, apps get the list of books defined in DynamoDB table on every index action. Books are defined in DynamoDB table and are being changed quite rarely. So I believe that some cache would be useful and could speed up my app.

What could be the best choice in this scenario? I think about Memcache or Redis, but may could you recommend me something better?

I prefer to run cache on every instance rather than as separate service.

Here I found interesting article about caching: https://www.speedshop.co/2015/07/15/the-complete-guide-to-rails-caching.html